# HorizontalSwipeJump Overriding Page Swipes

Tags: react-native, carousel

I'm using react-native Navigator's HorizontalSwipeJump to back swipe screens.

With a Carousel it seems HorizontalSwipeJump overrides the carousel swipes and swipes forward or backward without respecting hierarchy.

Any ideas on how to fix?! Could this be a hierarchy problem?

Please and thanks! <3